# Visual Studio Code - JavaScript - Intellisense not working properly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been using Visual Studio Code for a while and really like the editor.
So far the intellisense have been working fine for PowerShell which I use on a daily basis.

Just started to learn html, css and javascript through a beginners book and noticed the intellisense does not come with suggestions like I'm used to for Powershell.

For instance take this snippet of code:

[image]

There are no suggestions for the underlying methods like:

[image]

Is there an easy way to fix this?
From what I've read the VS Code editor should have basic native support for html, css and JavaScript. I also tried adding other extensions like "Babel JavaScript", "HTML CSS Support" for these languages but still the same.

Comment: You are right, it's supposed to work out of the box, try restarting Vs Code or updating to the latest vesion

Comment: I am able to reproduce this in my VS Code. After adding ```var``` keyword in front of ```timeNow```, everything works as expected, Intellisense does show up in the second line.

Comment: @GanHJ Thanks. Adding 'var' or 'let' in front of the variable name fixed it all. Not sure why the book didn't include this in the code examples.

Comment: Which book? Just curious.

Comment: @JoelPeltonen It's [Sams Teach Yourself
HTML, CSS, and JavaScript All in One](https://www.amazon.com/HTML-JavaScript-Sams-Teach-Yourself/dp/0672338084) . I enjoy it a lot. Seems to mostly focus on html and css in the first part of the book with some javascript in between. The last part is more javascript focused. The ebook is around 1000 pages (1700+ with index included)